# How is centos packages build?

Tags: centos, openldap, configuration

Where do I find information about how a specific package in centos is build. Ie. what flags has been used on ./configure etc.

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how slapd (openldap-servers) are build. Did they use "--enable-modules" when the package was configured. I guess not, but it would be interesting to get it verified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
yumdownloader --source openldap-servers
rpm -Uvh openldap-servers*
less rpmbuild/SPECS/openldap.spec
```

According to that `--enable-modules` was specified, by the way. :-)

Comment: Thanks man. But weird with the enable-modules thing. I have to look somewhere else to find a solution to my problem =)

Comment: Just create another question, I will do my best with that one, too. ;)